# prevent MYSQL from resetting Auto increment values on Server restart

Tags: mysql

We have a situation. We store id with auto increment and delete the rows to keep table clean. We do not want MYSQL to reset the auto increment when it gets rebooted accidentally. Though upon deleting MYSQL do not reset the auto inc counter and we are happy with that but occasionally MYSQL restart and that counter is reset to max(id) +1. We want to avoid that, is there a way we can tell MYSQL to keep the auto increment counter to where it was before the restart.

Answer (score 0):

It's know bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=199.
The bug is not solved yet.

The best workaround probably is to use sequences:
https://openquery.com.au/blog/implementing-sequences-using-a-stored-function-and-triggers