# Auto Increment has been reset back to 1 automatically

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, mariadb

I've just run into an issue which I'm not able to solve.

I have a database table `project_queues` which is used as a queue, where I store some records. When the records are processed, they are deleted. 
Deletion is invoked by rails construction `record.destroy` in a loop which triggers `DELETE record FROM table` on MySql database.

But now I've noticed, that in the table `project_queues` the **autoIncrement** **Id** (primary key) was set up back to **1**. (Which damaged my references in the audit table. The Same record now points to multiple different project queues)

```
show create table project_queues;

CREATE TABLE `project_queues` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ...
   ...
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

I do not use `TRUNCATE project_queues` or drop the table construction and created it again in code.

Did somebody run into a similar issue like me? I can't find any anomalies in the log either.

I'm using **Rails 5.2.3**, **MariaDB 10.1**.

The connection from the application to database enforces this SQL modes:

- NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO
- STRICT_ALL_TABLES
- NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
- NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
- NO_ZERO_DATE
- NO_ZERO_IN_DATE
- ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO

But I don't think that these have something to do with AI.

Comment: Maybe I found similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786800/prevent-mysql-from-resetting-auto-increment-values-on-server-restart

Comment: But you _did_ restart the server after deleting the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solved

I've upgraded `10.1.29-MariaDB MariaDB Server` to `10.2.8-MariaDB MariaDB Server`

Version >= [10.2.4](http://%20https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-1024-release-notes/) has solved the resetting of Auto Increment value

Comment: Also MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

Auto_increment can be reset by updates. Since you're using it as a queue I suppose you don't make updates, but it's worth asking.

Also, what table implementation do you use, MyIsam, InnoDB, other ... ?

Comment: No, I do not use updates, only Insert and Delete. 
Table implementation ENGINE=InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Well ok, I found the problem (it's a known issue from 2013).

Here is how to reproduce the problem.

```
# Your MariaDB Server version: 10.1.29-MariaDB MariaDB Server
# Engine InnoDB

create database ai_test;
use ai_test;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ai_test(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                                   a VARCHAR(50));

show table status like 'ai_test' 
  >  Auto_increment: 1

INSERT INTO ai_test(a) VALUES ('first');
INSERT INTO ai_test(a) VALUES ('second');
INSERT INTO ai_test(a) VALUES ('third');

show table status like 'ai_test' 
  >  Auto_increment: 4

MariaDB [ai_test]> Delete from ai_test where a = 'first';
MariaDB [ai_test]> Delete from ai_test where a = 'second';
MariaDB [ai_test]> Delete from ai_test where a = 'third';

show table status like 'ai_test' \G
  >  Auto_increment: 4

# Restart Server
sudo service rh-mariadb101-mariadb stop
sudo service rh-mariadb101-mariadb start

show table status like 'ai_test' \G
  >  Auto_increment: 1
```

I'll try to find some workaround to solve this problem, but I think this cause havoc to many use cases which refers to some archive tables or something like that.

**References**:

- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64287
- https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=6204
- https://openquery.com.au/blog/implementing-sequences-using-a-stored-function-and-triggers